# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I use chrome standalone driver with selenium. Open the window in a new tab and switch to it (python). The number of windows equals two but the browser crashed in opened one with

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not
>   reachable

```
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_60'

Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=49.0.2623.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]

Stacktrace:
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (None:-2)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (None:-1)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (None:-1)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (None:-1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable (ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed (ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute (RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute (RemoteWebDriver.java:670)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getWindowHandles (RemoteWebDriver.java:525)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor185.invoke (None:-1)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (None:-1)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (None:-1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke (EventFiringWebDriver.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getWindowHandles (None:-1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.getWindowHandles (EventFiringWebDriver.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.GetAllWindowHandles.call (GetAllWindowHandles.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.GetAllWindowHandles.call (GetAllWindowHandles.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (None:-1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run (DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (None:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (None:-1)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (None:-1)
```

Comment: Without your code or a URL we will likely be guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading latest chrome driver as of date from below link:-

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

and provide the path of latest chrome binary to your script.

Hope it will help you :)